# Hide/Remove core simpleTests in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, testing

I would like to remove the core tests that show up when I activate the Testing (simpletest) module. I have created my own tests for custom modules and I would like those to be the only testing options available to the user. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`hook_simpletest_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21simpletest%21simpletest.api.php/function/hook_simpletest_alter/7.x), e.g.

```
function hook_simpletest_alter(&$groups) {
  // An alternative session handler module would not want to run the original
  // Session HTTPS handling test because it checks the sessions table in the
  // database.
  unset($groups['Session']['testHttpsSession']);
}
```